# How to force driver to device match in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, kernel

I have a piece of USB hardware, for which I know the driver.

However, the vendor id and product id do not match the VID, PID pair registered in the driver.

Is there a way in Linux to force a driver to be associated with a known device, that do not involve kernel module recompilation to add a PID / VID pair?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Find the module in the `sysfs` tree. In this case it was  in

```
/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp2101
```

In this directory, there is a `new_id` file entry that can be used to dynamically add VID PID pair like this :

```
echo VID PID >new_id
```

Here is a [LWN entry](http://lwn.net/Articles/160944/) about this feature

Comment: +1: Nice answer. On my machine for USB, I found paths as: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb4/idVendor and /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb4/idProduct

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to make this change permanent and assign specific driver to device (VID, PID)  you may find [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165845/156466) answer useful.

For example create new file`/etc/udev/rules.d/98-joystick.rules` with content:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1345", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6005", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe xpad" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1345 6005 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/xpad/new_id'"
```

Replace `1345` with your VID and `6005` with your PID.

Replace `xpad` with appropriate driver.

Run following command:

```
$ sudo udevadm control --reload
```

Unplug and plug your device back and check if the new driver is loaded.

Example shown here is for fixing driver issues with `Speedlink Strike FX Gamepad  (SL-6537-BK)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need actually recompile the whole kernel, recompiling only relevant kernel module with updated match table will be enough, in case that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442833/forcing-driver-to-device-match#442867) answer, does not work on your kernel.