# How to change mode(or product ID) of SIMCOM module (SIM8262E-M2)

Tags: linux, serial-port, at-command, modem, libqmi

I messed up. I got this SIMCOM module recently, with 5G support.
[SIM8262E-M2](https://www.simcom.com/product/SIM8262X-M2.html)
This is based on Snapdragon X62 Modem.

It has 4 modes(or product IDs) of operation:
`at+cusbcfg=?` gives the following: 9001,9003,9011,901e
The default factory mode is 9001.
All the modes (except 901E) provide `/dev/ttyUSB` (I learnt the hard way!) and you can issue AT commands via those(using minicom etc.)
I mistakenly changed the mode to 901E, now I'm unable to get any serial ports from this!

however this still has `/dev/cdc-wdm0`
I can use qmicli and mbimcli to interact:

```
[xplore@fedora ~]$ sudo qmicli --device=/dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-proxy --dms-get-operating-mode
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Operating mode retrieved:
    Mode: 'online'
    HW restricted: 'no'
```

My question:
How do I change the mode back to one of (9001,9003,9011) ? OR is there any way to issue AT commands via qmicli/mbimcli ?

I have also tried the following(refer this [post](https://techship.com/faq/how-to-guide-automated-always-on-connection-with-simcom-sim8202x-m2-series-in-linux-using-the-rndis-usb-mode/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442833/forcing-driver-to-device-match)):

```
[root@fedora xplore]# modprobe option
[root@fedora xplore]# echo 1e0e 9011 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

But after running this I don't see any `/dev/ttyUSB*` devices. (do I need to do anything else here?, I'm clearly not an expert in Linux)

Currently it shows up as:

```
[root@fedora xplore]# lsusb
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1e0e:901e Qualcomm / Option SDXLEMUR-LITE-MTP _SN:1505A7A0
```

dmesg output:

```
[ 2449.622442] usb 8-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2449.635211] usb 8-2: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
[ 2449.636702] usb 8-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1e0e, idProduct=901e, bcdDevice= 5.04
[ 2449.636704] usb 8-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2449.636704] usb 8-2: Product: SDXLEMUR-LITE-MTP _SN:1505A7A0
[ 2449.636705] usb 8-2: Manufacturer: SIMCOM
[ 2449.636706] usb 8-2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 2449.803329] cdc_mbim 8-2:1.2: setting rx_max = 16384
[ 2449.803997] cdc_mbim 8-2:1.2: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[ 2449.804219] cdc_mbim 8-2:1.2 wwan0: register 'cdc_mbim' at usb-0000:6b:00.0-2, CDC MBIM, 16:dd:bf:a1:af:08
[ 2449.816224] cdc_mbim 8-2:1.2 wwp107s0u2i2: renamed from wwan0
```

I also tried the following:
Enabled debug mode for ModemManager

```
sudo mmcli -m 0 --command="AT"
error: command failed: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Connected: No AT port available to run command'
```

But it shows that AT port isn't exposed.

Please help me out here, this devices is expensive for me and the device has extensive AT commands documentation, without which I cannot use it much.

More Documentation:
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/c/c6/SIM82XX_SIM83XX_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.02.pdf
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/USB_TO_M.2_B_KEY#Working_With_SIM82XX_Module
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM8262E-M2_5G_HAT
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5417a7e482962952e622eabd60cd3600dd65dedf

Comment: i was following the instruction on connecting the SIM8200EA-M2 5G to RPi4, but the is no Qualcomm devices get recognized on USB ports, is there any step missing on the guide?  (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM8200EA-M2_5G_HAT#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi). i can't get it work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed!
However the fix isn't a solution to this problem.
I fixed it by getting latest drivers for Windows, after installing them I could see COM ports open!
I used putty to connect to serial port and change the mode back:

```
AT+CUSBCFG=USBID,1E0E,9003
```

Answer (score 2):

> OR is there any way to issue AT commands via qmicli/mbimcli?

I do not know about those two programs, however I have written a program [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) for the sole purpose of running AT commands from the command line. Based on example given in the documentation<sup>1</sup> and assuming `/dev/cdc-wdm0` is the serial device for AT commands you should be able to run

```bash
echo AT+CUSBCFG=usbid,1e0e,9011 | atinout - /dev/cdc-wdm0 -
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
Looking at the documentation for this command I cringe over how fundamentally broken and incorrect the syntax for this command is because string parameters **shall** always be enclosed with double quote characters, which for zero good reasons is not the case here. The person(s) implementing the AT+CUSBCFG command clearly did not properly understand AT commands.

The documentation references *V.25ter* which is sort of correct, but still not a great sign since the reference ought to be *V.250* which *V.25ter* was [renamed to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_AT_command_set#V.250) "just" 24 years ago after only 3 years of existence:

> The ITU-T established a standard in its V-Series Recommendations, V.25ter, in 1995 in an attempt to establish a standard for the command set again. It was renamed V.250 in 1998

And [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) is crystal clear on what proper syntax is:

> 5.4.2 Values
>
> ...
> value shall consist of either a numeric constant or a string constant.
>
> 5.4.2.1 Numeric constants
>
> Numeric constants are expressed in decimal, hexadecimal, or binary.
> ...
>
> 5.4.2.2 String constants
>
> String constants shall be bounded at the beginning and end by the double-quote character
> ...

and the above was definitely present from the very start in V.25ter so there is no excuse for this terrible wrong AT command syntax.

Comment: Hey Man, Thanks for the answering, however I do not think that /dev/cdc-wdm0 is serial port for AT commands. 
I ran the command that you have mentioned and it just get's stuck.:
[xplore@fedora ~]$ echo 'AT+CUSBCFG=usbid,1e0e,9001' |sudo atinout - /dev/cdc-wdm0 -
 

^C
[xplore@fedora ~]$ 

I have tried earlier using minicom :

 like I have mentioned in the post, for serial the device was showing ```/dev/ttyUSB*``` earlier however after changing the product ID via AT, I'm not able to see the ttyUSB .

Comment: I have tried  minicom earlier on /dev/cdc-wdm0 but no use.